# How to save .zip to a folder using ZipArchive?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-ziparchive

I did the following, but i don't see the zip file in the directroy. C#

```
  public static void AddToZip(string fileToAdd, string directory)
    {
        string entryName = fileToAdd.Replace(directory, string.Empty);
        string archiveName = entryName.Replace(Path.GetExtension(entryName), ".zip");

        using (ZipArchive za = ZipFile.Open(archiveName, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
        {
            za.CreateEntryFromFile(fileToAdd, entryName, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
        }
    }
```

and this is the link i followed.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is that hungarian notation you're using?

Comment: What is `sArchiveName` when you open the ZipFile?

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: no error, it is smooth, just the zip file doesn't exist in the folder provided.

Comment: did you debug the path? was it right?

Comment: `sFileToAdd.Replace(sDirectory, string.Empty);` replace with `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sFileToAdd)`

Comment: @dcastro, yes i'm. Learnt from old fashoined guy, still haven't changed, yet.

Comment: @aleha, that doesn't give me the right name of for the zip entry.

Comment: Thats all the code is there.

Comment: To be sure, you want to create a zip archive in the parent directory of a file. The zip archive should contains the file from the directory. Is it what you want ?

Comment: @aloisdg, Yes, the zip archive should be in parent directory and the file in that zip archive should be the one i send it to in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working after some trial and error.

```
public static void AddToZip(string fileToAdd, string directory)
    {
        string entryName = fileToAdd.Replace(directory, string.Empty);//name of the file inside zip archive
        string tempDir = Path.Combine(directory, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(entryName));

        if (Directory.Exists(tempDir)) DeleteDirector(tempDir);
        else Directory.CreateDirectory(tempDir);

        System.IO.File.Move(fileToAdd, Path.Combine(tempDir, entryName));//as the CreateFromDirectoy add all the file from the directory provided, we are moving our file to temp dir.

        string archiveName = entryName.Replace(Path.GetExtension(entryName), ".zip"); //name of the zip file.

        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(tempDir, Path.Combine(directory, archiveName));
        DeleteDirector(tempDir);
    }
    private static void DeleteDirector(string deletedir)
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(deletedir))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(file);
        }
        Directory.Delete(deletedir);
    }
```

I know this is not the best solution. so, you are welcome to modify/improve it.